# Using PHP variable to search a value in an array and then remove it

Tags: php, arrays

Hey guys im trying to search an array for an value and then remove it. But im searching with a php variable and that seems to be the problem. So this is what I have so far:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Admin'])){
    $arr = array('HAUGMA1', 'sdasd', 'dasdasda', 'sadasd');
    $key=array_search($_REQUEST['Admin'],$arr);
    if($key!==false) 
        unset($arr[$key]);
    print_r($arr);
}
```

The `$_REQUEST` retrieves the value `HAUGMA1` but when I print out the array it didn't remove `HAUGMA1` from it. What am I doing wrong? When I'm using this:

```
$key=array_search('HAUGMA1',$arr);
```

It is working.

Comment: what is the actual value of $_REQUEST['Admin'] when you echo it?

Comment: you have used second `if` wrong. it should be `if($key!=FALSE)`

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia not according to the manual... http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: @thescientist the value is `HAUGMA1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in relation to the value that is coming from the `$_REQUEST` variable.
I made the following test to show two questions:

```
//Array definition
$arr = array('HAUGMA1', 'sdasd', 'dasdasda', 'sadasd');
//Search
$admin = 'dasdasda';

/* First sample */

$time = microtime();

$arr = array_filter($arr, function($key) use($admin) {
    return $key != $admin;
});

print_r($arr);
echo '<br>Execution time: '.(microtime()-$time).'<br>';

/* Second sample */

$time = microtime();

$key = array_search($admin, $arr);
if($key !== false)
    unset($arr[$key]);

print_r($arr);
echo '<br>Execution time: '.(microtime()-$time).'<br>';
```

**First:** using the `array_search` has approximately 4x faster than `array_filter`.

**Second:** the way that your script is, the item is removed from the array without problem. Try to debug the value that is coming from the variable `$_REQUEST`

Comment: an `var_dump` of `$_REQUEST['Admin']` gives me `string(9) "HAUGMA1 "`

Comment: That's the problem. Use the "trim" to remove extra spaces in `$_REQUEST` variable: `array_search(trim($_REQUEST['Admin']), $arr);`

Answer (score 0):

array_search is case sensitive. Use strtoupper and trim in order to conform the incoming variable to the values in your array. trim() will get rid of trailing white space and other unwanted characters.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Admin'])){
    $arr = array('HAUGMA1', 'SDASD', 'ETC');
    $key = array_search(strtoupper(trim($_REQUEST['Admin'])), $arr);
    if($key !== false){ 
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    print_r($arr);
 }
```

Comment: nope not wokring result is:`Array ( [0] => HAUGMA1 [1] => SDASD [2] => ETC ) `

Comment: Can you var_dump($_REQUEST['Admin']) and tell us the result?

Comment: The result is: `string(9) "HAUGMA1 "`

Answer (score 0):

try this (closure PHP >= 5.3)

```
$admin = $_REQUEST['Admin'];

$arr = array_filter($arr, function($key) use($admin) {
    return $key != $admin;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When i set manually `$_REQUEST['Admin']` to "HAUGMA1", it's working. Are you sure there is no whitespace in the beginning or the end of your string ?

Try with this :

```
$key = array_search(trim($_REQUEST['Admin']), $arr);
```

Comment: In Wayne Whitty's response he used `strtoupper` and `trim` and the OP said that it still wasn't working.